# Can this dataset be separated linearly?

Tags: classification, dataset, activation-function, linearly-separable

[image: ![Dataset](]

Is this dataset linearly separable? If not, can it be converted into one by applying some function as it seems to follow the same pattern?

Also, which classification algorithms could be used to fit this dataset?

Comment: no it is not linearly separable. But it seems to have periodic pattern, so a periodic transformation (eg modulo) can make it linearly separable

Comment: @NikosM. Would it be possible to show a visualization or a graph with the modulo transformed points? Also, can a sine function be a valid transformation? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You simply map the X2 feature back into the first quarter (approximately, eg by using modulo or other equivalent operation), X1 remains the same. Then it is linearly separable as your sketch suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nikos said, the dataset is not linearly separable: one cannot draw a single straight line which has all the red points on one side and all the green points on the other.

There is an obvious repetition pattern on $x_2$. Let's assume that $x_2$ ranges from 0 to 100 on this graph, the value $x_2$ modulo 50 would make it linearly separable. That would be feature engineering.

Notice that $x_1$ doesn't have any impact on the class. So imho the best algorithm in this case is to just map $x_2$ intervals to the class.